# AWS Amplify cannot enter user keys

Tags: aws-amplify

I am going through the tutorial for AWS Amplify and I get to the point where I am to enter the keys for the newly created user

I get prompted for the access key:

```
Enter the access key of the newly created user:
? accessKeyId:  [hidden]
```

I paste in the value for this and the secret key. But then it seems to fail with

```
You did NOT enter valid keys.
New user setup failed.
Error: New user setup failed.
    at C:\Users\RKevi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-provider-awscloudformation\lib\setup-new-user.js:108:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Am I to type in the keys manually?

Thank you.